# how to make a custom comment style in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I got a source code commented like below.

```
// //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// //======================= Variable Declaration =================================
```

Is there any way to make a comment like the above in vs code.

I only got single and multiline comments.

But I want the above custom style.

Comment: Go to keyboard shortcuts and type "add line comment" and change the keyboard shortcut. There is another shortcut called 'remove line comment.' with which you can remove comments. :) I have it as CTRL + Q and CTRL + Shift + Q respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a snippet to do that.  In one of your snippets files:

```
"Variable Declaration Comment": {
    "prefix": "_gc",          // whatever trigger you want
    "body": [
      "$LINE_COMMENT $LINE_COMMENT------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
      "$LINE_COMMENT $LINE_COMMENT======================= ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT} =================================$0",
    ],
    "description": "Insert a Variable Declaration comment header"
}
```

That will use whatever the line comment style is for the type of file you are in: `$LINE_COMMENT`.

You could set that to a keybinding like this (in your `keybindings.json` file):

```
{
  "key": "alt+q",    // whatever keybinding you want 
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "name": "Variable Declaration Comment"
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

---

If you want to get fancy and see how to build other custom comment blocks, you can do this with an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview).  Use this keybinding in your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+f",                  // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    
    "replace": [
      "$${",
      
        "const lineLength = 80;",    // how long you want the block
        // what is the length of the comment characters in this language
        "const commentCharsLength = 2 * (`${LINE_COMMENT}`.length) + 1;", // + 1 for the space between comment markers

        // select the text you want to wrap first
        "const selectionLength = `${selectedText}`.length;",
        "const gapLength = 1;",  // the spaces around the text
        
        "let str = `${LINE_COMMENT} ${LINE_COMMENT}` + '-'.padEnd(lineLength - commentCharsLength, '-') + `\n`;",

        "const totalSpacers = lineLength - commentCharsLength - selectionLength - (2 * gapLength);",
        "const beforeSelectionLength = totalSpacers/2 - commentCharsLength/2;",
        "const afterSelectionLength = totalSpacers/2 +  commentCharsLength/2;",

        // ${LINE_COMMENT} in backticks to treat as a string
        "str += `${LINE_COMMENT} ${LINE_COMMENT}` + '='.padEnd(beforeSelectionLength, '=') + ` `;",

        "if (selectionLength %2 === 0) str +=  `${selectedText} ` + '='.padEnd(afterSelectionLength, '=');",
        "if (selectionLength %2 === 1) str +=  `${selectedText} ` + '='.padEnd(afterSelectionLength+1, '=');",

        "return str;",
      
      "}$$"
    ],
    
    "restrictFind": "line",
    // "postCommands": "cancelSelection"
  },
  // "when": "editorLangId == javascript"
}
```

As you can see, you can write javascript in a keybinding (or setting).

[image: demo creating a custom comment block with javascript in a keybinding]

Comment: Yes, this is working. but a simple problem is that, when I select a sentence and press alt + q, it shows variable declaration. I just need to replace it with what I selected. how to do that?

Comment: for  example, if I select "controller" text, it should replaced with "variable declaration".

Comment: If you select "controller" that should appear where the "Variable Declaration" text is?  And "controller" is the only thing on that line?  I edited the answer is what you select is put in the middle - you'll have to pad the lines with `=`'s to match the upper line - no big deal.

Comment: yep...its working. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [HyperSnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips)

Define the following snippet in the `all.hsnips` file

```
snippet comment "Comment Section"
// //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// //``s = '='.repeat((78-(t[0].length + 2))/2); rv = s;`` $1 ``rv = '='.repeat(78-(t[0].length + 2 + s.length));``
endsnippet
```

If you type `comment` and select the snippet with `Tab` you can type the text and the `===` strings adjust to keep the text centered.

You can also cut some text - start the snippet - and paste the text.

Comment: where is all.hsnips file?

Comment: @Mahi Use the command: **Hypersnips Open Snippet file**, see the page of the extension